# Sorting a generic list by an external sort order

Tags: c#, linq

I have a generic list

Simplified example

```
var list = new List<string>()
  {
    "lorem1.doc",
    "lorem2.docx",
    "lorem3.ppt",
    "lorem4.pptx",
    "lorem5.doc",
    "lorem6.doc",
  };
```

What I would like to do is to sort these items based on an external list ordering

In example

```
var sortList = new[] { "pptx", "ppt", "docx", "doc" };

// Or
var sortList = new List<string>() { "pptx", "ppt", "docx", "doc" };
```

Is there anything built-in to linq that could help me achieve this or do I have to go the foreach way?

Comment: You want to sort them and keep them in one list or would getting back groups be useful?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the list you can use `IndexOf` for `Enumerable.OrderBy`:

```
var sorted = list.OrderBy(s => sortList.IndexOf(Path.GetExtension(s)));
```

So the index of the extension in the `sortList`  determines the priority in the other list. Unknown extensions have highest priority since their index is -1.

But you need to add a dot to the extension to get it working:

```
var sortList = new List<string>() { ".pptx", ".ppt", ".docx", ".doc" };
```

If that's not an option you have to fiddle around with `Substring` or `Remove`, for example:

```
var sorted = list.OrderBy(s => sortList.IndexOf(Path.GetExtension(s).Remove(0,1)));
```

Comment: Just note that GetExtension() returns also the extension "dot", while sortList doesn't have it...

Comment: @digEmAll It's getting the extension from the filenames in the original list (e.g., "lorem1.doc")

Comment: Yes, but the problem is `GetExtension` will return something like `.ppt` so wont be found in the `sortedList`. Something like this solves `System.IO.Path.GetExtension(s).Substring(1)`. (Or, easier - just add the dot in the `sortedList`)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: `Path.GetExtension("lorem1.doc")` returns `".doc"` that is not present in sortList, so `IndexOf` returns -1 ...

Comment: @Tim - `at the colon` should be `add the dot` no?

Answer (score 6):

This solution will work even if some file names do not have extensions:

```
var sortList = new List<string>() { "pptx", "ppt", "docx", "doc" };
var list = new List<string>()
  {
    "lorem1.doc",
    "lorem2.docx",
    "lorem3.ppt",
    "lorem4.pptx",
    "lorem5.doc",
    "lorem6.doc",
  };

var result = 
       list.OrderBy(f => sortList.IndexOf(Path.GetExtension(f).Replace(".","")));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Array.IndexOf() method:

```
var sortedList = list.OrderBy(i => sortList.IndexOf(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(i))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

A `sortDicionary` would be more efficient:

```
var sortDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int> {
    { ".pptx", 0 },
    { ".ppt" , 1 },
    { ".docx", 2 },
    { ".doc" , 3 } };

var sortedList = list.OrderBy(i => {
    var s = Path.GetExtension(i);
    int rank;
    if (sortDictionary.TryGetValue(s, out rank))
        return rank;
    return int.MaxValue; // for unknown at end, or -1 for at start
});
```

This way the lookup is `O(1)` rather than `O(# of extensions)`.

Also, if you have a large number of filenames and a small number of extensions, it might actually be faster to do

```
var sortedList = list
    .GroupBy(p => Path.GetExtension(p))
    .OrderBy(g => {
        int rank;
        if (sortDictionary.TryGetValue(g.Key, out rank))
            return rank;
        return int.MaxValue; // for unknown at end, or -1 for at start
    })
    .SelectMany(g => g);
```

This means the sort scales by the number of distinct extensions in the input, rather than the number of items in the input.

This also allows you to give two extensions the same priority.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way that does not use `OrderBy`:

```
var res = 
sortList.SelectMany(x => list.Where(f => Path.GetExtension(f).EndsWith(x)));
```

Note that the complexity of this approach is `O(n * m)` with `n = sortList.Count` and `m list.Count`.

The `OrderBy` approach worst-case complexity is instead `O(n * m * log m)` but probably in general it will be faster (since `IndexOf` does not result always in `O(n)` ). However with small `n` and `m` you won't notice any difference.

For big lists the fastest way ( complexity `O(n+m)` ) could be constructing a temporary lookup i.e. :

```
var lookup = list.ToLookup(x => Path.GetExtension(x).Remove(0,1));
var res = sortList.Where(x => lookup.Contains(x)).SelectMany(x => lookup[x]);
```